# How to mask reverse lookup for domains?

Tags: reverse-dns

is there a way to block reverse lookup sites so people can't see the other sites hosted on an IP?

Thanks.

Comment: I agree there isn't really a way to block reverse lookups. If you want the sites to appear independent, you will probably need to get an IP address for each site. The sites should still be able to be hosted on the same machine, even with the same NIC, but that NIC will be bound to multiple IP addresses and will answer for all the sites.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.  Even if you block than through DNS, other people can still perform forward lookups and identify the same IP for multiple hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse lookups are ultimately the same as forward lookups in that you can't find the records if they aren't published.  It would be up to your DNS provider to remove the records from the reverse zone.

For example, 192.168.1.x are generally in the 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa zone.  Thus, 192.168.1.5 is looked up as the 5 record in 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  So, to not have 192.168.1.5 be resolvable, you would make sure 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa does not have a PTR record for 5 pointing at the name.

So basically, talk to whoever controls the DNS servers for the IP addresses in question and ask them to remove the entries.